# iOS / iPadOS mouse scrolling not working

Tags: ios, ipad, mouse, ipados

I´m currently checking out the mouse support in iPadOS 13.4 on my gen 3 iPad Air. Scrolling does not seem to work anywhere. Is this by design or do I need to configure something to make it work?

According to the [iPadOS features](https://www.apple.com/ipados/features/), it supports 3rd party Bluetooth mice

> **Mouse and trackpad support**
>
> iPadOS supports Magic Keyboard, Magic Mouse, and Magic Trackpad, as well as third‑party mice using Bluetooth and USB.

I tested it with the gen 2 Magic Mouse and I`m also using the Apple Smart Keyboard.

Comment: I too am having this issue.  I was going to post a question myself, but you got it first, so +1  My Logitech mouse pairs with my iPad with no issues, but does nothing once connected.

Comment: I have this issue with my traditional wired mouse connected through a USB-C dongle. Can’t seem to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The scrolling feature appears broken since I have the same issue. A workaround is to move the cursor to the area you want to scroll. Press and hold down the mouse button and move the mouse forward or backward. This will scroll the area you selected.

Comment: Did it ever work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Using Magic Trackpad 2 worked for me. I can scroll on a document, a webpage in Safari / Chrome, and also some builtin software where scrolling is supported.

Although interestingly, any gesture that requires three fingers does not work for me.